# zsh: Is it possible to trace all functions and commands called and aliases expanded during a command’s execution?

Tags: zsh, trace, tracing

I want something like this:

```
# source:
a() b mp3 m4a "$@"
b() eval "${1}-to-${2} $@:q"
alias mp3-to-m4a='ffmpeg ...'
# 
$ traceall a a.mp3 a.m4a
 # should return:
 Functions:
 a
 b
 Aliases:
 mp3-to-m4a
 commands:
 ffmpeg
```

Answer (score 2):

You might look at `trap` with the `DEBUG` pseudosignal. This only triggers for commands and functions, though, and only after alias expansion. You want to read the details in the zsh manual, because it runs a command or function giving it information about what's about to be executed, rather than recording information directly; you could use this hypothetically to implement a full debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Turn xtrace globally:

```
> set -x; a a.mp3 a.m4 ; set +x
```

or turn on xtrace for functions, then execute it:

```
> typeset -tf a   # turns on xtrace for function a and below
> a a.mp3 a.m4

> typeset -Tf a   # turns on xtrace for function a only
> a a.mp3 a.m4
```